In a constructor i am trying to give default values. Getting an error: The default value of an optional parameter must be constant
const GradientContainer.purple(
  {super.key,
  this.colorsList = ***[
    const Color.fromARGB(123, 69, 2, 74),
    const Color.fromARGB(123, 233, 177, 237)
  ]***,
  this.textToBePlaced = 'New Constructor'});

Error part inside *** - ***.
I'm assuming this is because Lists are mutable so they cannot be considered as a constant?
If not, why am I getting this error?

Was i getting this error because Lists are mutable? Just to understand the error. @Nagual

@Yuichi, yes arrays are mutable. As far as i know, you could still add/remove items to the array when its constant - you just may not re-assign them.

While the items in the array are constant, the array itself is not.
You can fix that by adding the const keyword in front of the array as such:
const GradientContainer.purple(
  {super.key,
  this.colorsList = const [
    Color.fromARGB(123, 69, 2, 74),
    Color.fromARGB(123, 233, 177, 237)
  ],
  this.textToBePlaced = 'New Constructor'});

